# PL/SQL compilation error during update

Tags: sql, plsql, cursor, sql-update, plsqldeveloper

Query

```
DECLARE
  v_vendor_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR vp_rec IN ( SELECT * FROM vpprocess )
    LOOP
      SELECT i.vendor_id INTO v_vendor_id FROM item i, lineitems l WHERE l.itemid = i.itemid AND l.id = vp_rec.lineitemid;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN no_data_found THEN SELECT 0 INTO v_vendor_id FROM dual;
      UPDATE vpprocess SET vendorid = v_vendor_id WHERE vpprocessid = vp_rec.vpprocessid;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Error Message

```
 Error starting at line 1 in command:
DECLARE
  v_vendor_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR vp_rec IN ( SELECT * FROM vpprocess )
    LOOP
      SELECT i.vendor_id INTO v_vendor_id FROM item i, lineitems l WHERE l.itemid = i.itemid AND l.id = vp_rec.lineitemid;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN no_data_found THEN SELECT 0 INTO v_vendor_id FROM dual;
      UPDATE vpprocess SET vendorid = v_vendor_id WHERE vpprocessid = vp_rec.vpprocessid;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 7, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:

   begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe
ORA-06550: line 11, column 7:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:

   ;
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax for your `FOR` loop. The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. Instead of the word `BEGIN` PUT `LOOP`.

As a personal rule, I never use `BEGIN` IN PL/SQL with very few exceptions, such as if I need to trap exceptions only on a certain block of code, and that code isn't already a loop or function body or whatever.

Edit based on OP's edit: this appears to be one of those cases. Try the following:

```
DECLARE
  v_vendor_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR vp_rec IN ( SELECT * FROM vpprocess )
    LOOP
     BEGIN
       SELECT i.vendor_id INTO v_vendor_id FROM item i, lineitems l WHERE l.itemid = i.itemid AND l.id = vp_rec.lineitemid;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN no_data_found THEN v_vendor_id := 0;
      END;  
      UPDATE vpprocess SET vendorid = v_vendor_id WHERE vpprocessid = vp_rec.vpprocessid;
    /* END; has been removed */
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Dan: i did try replacing LOOP but it didn't help. I am updating the error as well as query.

Comment: Ok I updated my answer. I don't have Oracle in front of me any more so this is a guess. But basically the `EXCEPTION WHEN` is a block-scope feature so you need to create an inner block around _only_ those statements (in your case, a single statement) where you want to trap exceptions.